# Android Studio error about my windows account name?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, gradle, directory

My username on windows 10 is **F!** (with ! on it).

Unfortunately, android studio sometimes has problem with '!' in the directory address and can't recognize that.

For example whenever I try to add a line in build.gradle file such as:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I'll get this error message:

> Error:(32, 0) C:\Users\F (The system cannot find the file specified).

As you dear programmers can see the full address isn't shown after F letter and before '!' sign.
Please help and tell me what can I do.

- P.S. 1: I can't change or re-install my windows right now and it
  won't create another user account for me (tried so much).
- P.S. 2: I copied .gradle folder inside F! directory somewhere else
  and referenced android studio gradle section in settings to that. But
  still I have problems in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your windows account name.

Comment: The folder name remains unchanged C:\Users\F!

Comment: Maybe change install directory of android studio and that stuff? Into another drive maybe?

Comment: uhhh... change all the folders' names which have F!?